# Javascript, add dynamic class to all elements of same type

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was wondering how to add dynamic class to all elements of certain type on a html page using javascript?

I need this to distinguish input elements in my page.

Example:

```
<p class="n+1">input</p>
<p class="n+2">input</p>
```

Is there a way?

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('p').attr('class', 'classtobeadded')` adds the class 'classtobeadded' to all `p` tags

Comment: I know that, but I need it to be dynamic. First P gets class="p1", second P gets class="p2" etc.

Comment: It's *well worth* our time to read through [the jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It only takes  an hour, two tops, and it pays you back that time immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You select the elements with `$()`, then loop through adding a class via [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) passing in a function; jQuery will call the function with the 0-based index of the each element in the document.

> First P gets class="p1", second P gets class="p2" etc

Because the index is 0-based, we'll have to add one to it:

```
$("p").addClass(function(index) {
    return "p" + (index + 1);
});
```

**Live Example**:

```js
$("p").addClass(function(index) {
  return "p" + (index + 1);
});
```

```css
.p1 {
  color: blue;
}
.p2 {
  color: green;
}
.p3 {
  color: #990;
}
```

```html
<p>one</p>
<p>two</p>
<p>three</p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect! This is going to help a lot with my projects. Just tell me, in terms of speed, how good is this? Can it be problematic?

Comment: @MarcSommerson: I just tried it using the [ECMAScript 6 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html), which is a fairly large document with 3,732 `p` elements. Took 36ms. So I tried it again using **all** elements on that page (87,671 of them). Took 575ms. So I'd say likely to be fast enough for most purposes.

Comment: Thank you. You are very helpfull. Best answer I ever got on this service :)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$('p').each(function(i,op)
{
   $(this).addClass("p" + (i+1));
});
```

This would add class "p1,p2,p2... " to each unique p element.

Comment: Most of jQuery's setters, including `addClass`, accept a function like `each` does. (See my answer for an example.) No need for `each` for this sort of thing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Thanks for the info.